# How add Params and How get String ? (java,httpclient 4.X)

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

Code Http get request:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

    // Create local HTTP context
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    // Bind custom cookie store to the local context
    localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

    HttpGet first = new HttpGet("http://vk.com");
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(first, localContext);

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
        int l;
        byte[] tmp = new byte[2048];
        while ((l = instream.read(tmp)) != -1) {
        }
    }
```

How get responce STRING ?

And I need create request POST, add params and auto redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a quicker way to do this but this will get you the response as a string:

```
        InputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line = r.readLine()) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        in.close();
        String s = sb.toString();
```

To create a post request use:

```
        PostMethod post = new PostMethod("http://url.com");
        post.addParameter("param1name", "param1value");
```

Or HttpPost: http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

HttpClient should handle the automatic redirects for you

Comment: Thanks, how create POST request ?

Comment: How add 
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

client.getParams().setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY); ?